# How the time complexity O(n) is calculated?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

Lets assume the following code (Python)- Leader in the array

```
def goldenLeader(A):
    n = len(A)
    size=0
    for k in xrange(n):
       if (size == 0): size += 1
          value = A[k] else:
       if (value != A[k]): size -= 1
       else:
         size += 1
    candidate = -1 if (size > 0):
    candidate = value leader = -1
    count = 0
    for k in xrange(n):
        if (A[k] == candidate): count += 1
    if(count>n//2): leader = candidate
    return leader
```

So Since we are  traversing the array A twice ,the time complexity should be O(n + n)

But it is mentioned the time complexity to be O(n)

How come?

Comment: `O(n+n) == O(2n) == O(n)`. Big-O notation "hides" multiplicative constants; I recommend [reading up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) a bit on how it works.

Comment: It should be noted that O(n) and all other O's are sets, not numbers. A better way to phrase it is O(n+n) ∈ O(n).

Comment: @chepner if Big-O notation "hides" multiplicative constants; then O(m+n) should be O(m) if m>n.

Comment: @manishkumar m+n is arbitrary. O(m)==O(n) in your example, even if m>n, in terms of big O.

Comment: The running times of graph algorithms often have such a "split" input size to emphasize how the density of the graph affects the running time. Compare Dijkstra's algorithm for single-source shortest path (`O(m + n lg n)`), which is sensitive to the number of edges in the graph, with Floyd-Warshall's algorithm (`O(n^3)`) which is not.

Comment: But the split is meant to convey that `O(m + n)` is strictly superlinear only when `m` is as well.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the wonderful explanation i have no clue about. But that article was great help.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi They are sets, but the set's members are functions, not other `O` classes. `O(n+n) = O(2n) = O(n)` is correct.

Comment: @Ahmet `O(m) = O(n)` is not true in general. OP's statement that `O(m + n) = O(m)` is true only if `n(m) \in O(m)`, for example if `m(n) > n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O notation only cares about the order of `n` (in other words, the power of `n`). So, anything in which `n` is raised to the power of 1 is considered `O(n)`, eg `O(n)`, `O(2n)`, `O(n+1)` etc.

Similarly, `O(n^2)`, `O(n^2+2n)` etc are all considered to be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer.Hi Peeps!!! read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: "*in other words, the power of n*": It cares about much more, every non-constant factor is relevant, think e.g. `O(n log n)` which is not equal to `O(n)`.

Comment: @walnut of course, but note that I didn't refer to that case. `O(n*logn)` is not the same as `O(n+logn)`. `O(n+logn)` *is* `O(n)`